# Ubuntu. Раздать интернет по WI-FI (адаптер как точка доступа)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wifi, hotspot

ОС Ubuntu 16.04. К компьютеру подключение к интернету проводное. Вставил вайфай адаптер TP-link TL-WN725N, пытаюсь раздать через него интернет на мобильный.

Попробовал разные варианты, описанные в интернете, ничего не помогло. Телефон не видит сеть.
Возможно, есть какая-то программа, облегчающая это действие?
Не понимаю, почему стандартные средства линукс не срабатывают.
Пробовал в менеджере сети включить режим "точка доступа", - не помогло.
Создавал сеть вручную и подключался как к "скрытой сети", но вылетала ошибка, что устройство занято. Другими способами как-то еще получалось подключиться как к скрытой сети, но безрезультатно. Вроде бы пытается ПК подключиться, но не может и сеть разрывает.

Comment: http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/wifi_ap

Comment: пробовал. N: Файл «google.listsudo» в каталоге «/etc/apt/sources.list.d/» игнорируется, так как он не имеет неправильное расширение
E: Не удалось найти пакет wifi-hostapd-ap

Comment: дочитал ниже. пробую старый способ)

Comment: К слову. Я использую популярное скриптовое решение [create_ap](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap). На Ubuntu как раз работает.